# Settimeout in javascript performance issue

Tags: javascript, settimeout

### Problem

I am building **algorithms simulator** tool to simulate how algorithms work.
In **BFS** Algorithm I wanted to slow down the result display

So I used `setTimeout` function after each step to wait about 10ms before hitting the next step.
I used `promise` to be able to use `async` to easily wait the whole period and force the algorithm to stop till the wait function finishes

#### function implementation

```
function wait(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, time);
    })
}
```

#### BFS

```
while (queue.length) {
    let currentId = queue[index++];
    let tile = board.tileOf(currentId);
    tile.visit();
    if (currentId == targetId) {
        return;
    }
    await wait(10);
    for (let direction of DIRECTIONS) {
        let childId = moveId(currentId, direction);
        if (childId == undefined)
            continue;
        childId = parseInt(childId);
        let child = board.tileOf(childId);
        if (child.available()) {
            child.visit(true);
            queue.push(childId);
            pervNode[childId] = currentId;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is when I run the code it works fine but **sometimes** it takes very long time to display the solution more and more than just 10ms.

I am wondering why it's not accurate?
is this because of the approach that I am using?
and if there is a better solution what could it be?

[Try the tool from here](https://algo-simulator.netlify.app/graph_simulator/index.html)

Comment: Probably be better off not using a while loop. Make a function and call that with a delay.

Comment: this is a part of a function called BFS

Comment: So you should still be able to avoid the while loop.

Comment: Do you mean using recursive function?Could you please explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**i don't know the actual output but i think that could work**

```
while (queue.length) {
  let currentId = queue[index++];
  let tile = board.tileOf(currentId);
  tile.visit();
  if (currentId == targetId) {
    return;
  }
  let timer;
  const loop = () => {
    for (let direction of DIRECTIONS) {
      let childId = moveId(currentId, direction);
      if (childId == undefined) continue;
      childId = parseInt(childId);
      let child = board.tileOf(childId);
      if (child.available()) {
        child.visit(true);
        queue.push(childId);
        pervNode[childId] = currentId;
      }
    }
  };
  const listener = () => {
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      loop();
    }, 100);
  };
  listener();
}
```

Comment: It was very helpful to separate the `while` loop into a function, but I clear the timeout in different way. 
`let id = setTimeout(function () {`
Here I receive the timeout Id 
and inside the time out function I return that Id
`resolve(id)`
and then 
I clear the timeout here
`await wait(10, loop).then(id => clearTimeout(id));`

Answer (score 1):

As JavaScript is a single-thread language, when you place a function call inside *setTimeout()*, this function gets in a queue and waits until other functions in a call stack (that were called before it) are finished and the call stack become empty. Time you specify as a second parameter to *setTimeout()* starts counting from the moment of placing the function in the queue, but not always the queue is empty

Comment: Okay great, so since javascript runs on the client machine it varies from a machine to another depending on the machine resources and the applications running on that machine, am I right?
and if yes is there anyway to overcome this problem?

Comment: Or maybe if there is another solution!

Comment: Yes. Your JavaScript code should be less complex, more lightweight for your machine. Yet you could move part of your JavaScript logic to a server using NodeJS, thus shifting part of the work to the server. Your code snippet above looks like not complex, but I do not know exactly. For example, what board.tileOf(currentId) method do? Maybe it is performing some complex computation. Look at the others methods you used there and try to rewrite they, if possible, to decrease computation complexity